# Displaying all the Product of a Category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, products, phtml, external

how to display all the products of a category in a phtml file using an external file in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Create a block file at below location :

> app/code/Company/Module/Block/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block;
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $category->load($categoryId);
        return $category;
    }

    public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $products;
    }
}
?>
```

Now print the products using **.phtml** file :

```
$categoryId = 6; 
$categoryProducts = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    //print_r($product->getData());
    // printing category name and url
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```